# Julia not selecting MySQL database

Tags: julia

I've created a connection, and tried to execute a little sql into it ; im getting error `(1046): no database selected`

```
using DBInterface
using MySQL

con = DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection, "12345.rds.amazonaws.com", "admin", "54321")

sql = "CREATE TABLE friends2(last_name VARCHAR(10), first_name VARCHAR(20));"

DBInterface.execute(con, sql)

>> (1046): No database selected
```

When i run  `DBInterface.connect(MySQL.Connection, "12345.amazonaws.com", "admin", "54321")` i get :

```
MySQL.Connection(host="12345.rds.amazonaws.com", user="admin", port="3306", db="")
```

but if i enter the db when making the MySQL.Connection, i get  `(1049): Unknown database 'pg1'`

I also notice that even though i have run `add MySQL`, when i try to use some thing like `mysql_connect`, it doesnt work :

```
conn = mysql_connect( "12345.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com", "admin", "54321", "db")
>>> connect not defined
```

not sure where i messed up!

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you have to pass `; db="my_db"` to `DBInterface.connect`